# MySQL trigger - Adding from a separate table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `class` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_title` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_students` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `enrolment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ssn` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I am trying to do is when someone enters into 'Enrolment', if the class number entered matches an entry in 'Class', e.g. class number 2 - then i want what is typed into grade on 'Enrolment' (i.e 5) to add to whatever is already in number of students (Say if it's 10). In this case, the number of students would then say 15. This is the current trigger i have, however is not adding:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_add_one` AFTER INSERT ON `enrolment` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE class
 SET class.no_of_students = class.no_of_students + enrolment.grade WHERE class_no = NEW.class_no
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If anyone knows i'd be grateful for the help.

Comment: it should be `NEW.grade`, not `enrollemnt.grade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re not making changes with `SET class.no_of_students = class.no_of_students + enrolment.grade` if you’re not using enrolment.class_no to compare using where clause. Update it with NEW in place of enrolment if you’re using it:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_add_one` AFTER INSERT ON `enrolment` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE class
 SET class.no_of_students = class.no_of_students + NEW.grade WHERE class_no = NEW.class_no
$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use the `NEW` key instead of the name of table `enrolment`, try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_enrolment` AFTER INSERT ON `enrolment`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE class c  
    SET  
        c.no_of_students = c.no_of_students + NEW.grade   
    WHERE c.class_no = NEW.class_no;
END
```